# XML error: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing when i fetch the data through curl

Tags: php, curl

Can anybody suggest for the same

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

What URI are you using? Generally that means the address doesn't actually exist